# Second row header for fixed column in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to implement 3 rows header with fixed columns. So I appended the header rows to header on dataSrc callback. Below is how I added rows to header.

```
       function createHeaders(headeData){

       //.... creating firstHeaderRow
       //.... creating secondHeaderRow
            $('thead tr:first-child').before(firstHeaderRow);
            $('thead tr:last-child').after(secondHeaderRow);
       }
```

My table configured like below:

```
       $('#tableElement').DataTable({
           fixedColumns : {
               leftColumn: 5,
               rightColumn: 2
           },
           ajax:  {
               dataSrc: function(data){
                    createHeaders(data.headerData);
                }
           }
       });
```

The problem is in this case firstHeaderRow and secondHeaderRow is  not showing for fixedColumns. (It's showing for non-fixed columns correctly)

Based on documentation I think I need to call fnRedrawLayout()

So I added below lines at the bottom of createHeaders function

```
        var table = $('#tableElement').dataTable();
        var fc = new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table,  {
             leftColumn: 5,
             rightColumn: 2
        });
        fc.fnRedrawLayout();
```

However I am getting this error on FixedColumn.min

```
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null on below line.

       a.wrapper.style.height=e+"px";0<this.s.iLeftColumns&&(a.left.wrapper.style.width=g+"px",a.left.wrapper.style.height="1px",a.left.body.style.height=
```

Any help is much appreciated to get this working.

Comment: What version of datatables and fixed columns are you using? Maybe try calling `columns.adjust()` before redrawing, but after adding header rows? 
https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()

Comment: DataTable.version = "1.10.10" and FixedColumns.version = "3.2.0"

Comment: I added columns.adjust() before calling fc.fnRedrawLayout(); but didn't work. Still I'm getting the error for style. I added headers row not columns not sure why you suggested to adjust columns.

Comment: Are the header rows you add not separated by columns? I generally will construct my complex headers before i initialize the datatable, so I havn't ever tried to add them afterwards.
Have you tried calling: `fixedColumns().relayout()`, `rows().recalcHeight()`, or `fixedColumns().update()`? from this page: https://datatables.net/reference/api/#fixedcolumns

Comment: @chrisvanhooser Thank you so much. You made my day table.columns.adjust().fixedColumns().relayout(); worked!

Comment: Cool, i will post as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to call `columns.adjust()` and `fixedColumns().relayout()`.

This allows datatables to know about the header rows you added after it was constructed.

The fixed columns extension also need to be updated of all changes, because it basically created a new table to lay on top of the actual table.